# Bootstrap input field shrinks when set inline-block with another button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I simply want to display a "Choose file" input right from my input field, but I couldn't make it work.

What I have now is :

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="d-inline-block">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookTitle" aria-describedby="" placeholder="Enter Author">
   </div>
   <div class="d-inline-block">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
      <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Choose a file... <input type="file"  name="text_file" hidden>
      </label>
   </div>
   {{--<input type="file" class="btn"  name="text_file" />--}}
</div>
```

This gives me the following result :

[image]

The input should be three times bigger than this.

Then I tried this approach :

```
<div class="d-inline-block col-md-10">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title</label>
   <input type="text" class="inline-block form-control" id="bookTitle" aria-describedby="" placeholder="Enter document title">
</div>
<div class="d-inline-block col-sm-20">
   <label class="btn btn-default inline-block">
   <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Choose a file... <input type="file"     name="image" hidden>
   </label>
</div>
```

And this have me the following result :

[image]

In this case the input is the right size, but the "Choose file" is not where it's supposed to be.

Can someone help me make this work?

p.s the `div` is in a `<div class="row">`

Comment: try an input group https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an input group https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <label class="btn btn-default inline-block">
          <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Choose a file... <input type="file"     name="image" hidden>
        </label>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I tried it, but the "upload file" part won't work as how usually "Choose file" would and as mine does.

Comment: did you add the hidden input?  You may need to play with where the styling goes to make it look like a button.